# Data type of a foreign key referencing Identity?

Tags: h2, sqldatatypes

Basically, I'm confused about H2 use of Identity as [keyword](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition) and as [data type](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#identity_type).

**What's the proper data type of B.ref as a foreign key reference to A.id?**

```
create table A(id IDENTITY)
create table B(id IDENTITY, ref ???)
alter table B
      add constraint BRefOK foreign key (ref) references public.A;
```

The h2 console shows it's BIGINT(19), but I wonder if this is always the case and if there's a cleaner solution / alias.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any experience with H2, but from reading some of their docs and drawing on what I know of other databases, I would say this:

IDENTITY is not really a data type at all, from the database's point of view. IDENTITY causes the column to be declared as a type BIGINT, with the additional properties of having an associated sequence to supply its values and being the table's primary key.

If you feel it is "cleaner" to have the data types look like they match, I believe you could declare your columns like this instead and the meaning should be equivalent:

```
create table A(id BIGINT auto_increment primary key);
create table B(id BIGINT auto_increment primary key, ref BIGINT);
alter table B add constraint BRefOK foreign key (ref) references public.A;
```

However, someone who knows H2 should know that IDENTITY = BIGINT, so this shouldn't really be necessary.